# Mold behind shower tile - is landlord plan to disinfect and re-tile enough?

Tags: bathroom, mold, ceramic-tile, rental

I am a renter, and we just found what looks to be quite a bit of mold behind our shower tile (see picture!). Our landlord's plan is to remove the sections of tile that are affected (looks like bottom third of the shower), disinfect the walls, and retile it with large plastic panels. Is this enough? Should we be advocating for drywall replacement, testing a sample of the mold, or anything else as well? Would also welcome thoughts on if the disinfection should be with bleach, borax, or vinegar or otherwise! Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: As both a landlord and a DIYer, my course of action for what I see there would be to demo the entire tiled shower area and replace it with a set of plastic shower panels over new drywall or cement-fiber board. That original job (with the tiles just sort of glued to drywall with dabs of adhesive was an amateur hack-job and moisture has been leaking through the grout between the tiles for decades (probably).

Comment: The drywall behind that tile looks like it's taken enough moisture damage that it probably won't survive having the rest of the tile knocked off so your landlord will need to replace it.  It's mush now.  Going to take a lot of bull$#!t to reinforce it enough to reuse.  Replacing it should be enough for mold cleanup.  Once water isn't getting in there, it'll stop growing.

Comment: I vote for boric acid or borax, that stuff works miracles. I've seen shredded newspaper that was treated with it to make insulation in the 50s that got sopping wet for years with nary a spot of mold forming.

Answer (score 1):

NO. I don't think that's enough work. It looks so bad from the photo that I would expect it to be a major refurb requiring complete replacement of the Sheet rock with water resistant lining before the tiling was done.
Also you might want to check with the local building code and/or health inspectors. Black mould like that can be the root cause of all sorts of health problems.